# Curl : * Violate RFC 2616/10.3.2 and switch from POST to GET

Tags: php, post, curl, get, libcurl

I'm using curl to post to a script.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
```

But there's 301 redirect involved which casues curl to switch from POST to GET.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: https://myserver.org/php/callback-f.php
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 16 Nov 2011 17:21:06 GMT
< Server: lighttpd/1.4.28
* Connection #0 to host myserver.org left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://myserver.org/php/callback-f.php'
* Violate RFC 2616/10.3.2 and switch from POST to GET
* About to connect() to myserver.org port 443
```

Does anyone know how I can prevent curl from switching to GET please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CURLOPT_POSTREDIR` can be set to configure this behaviour (request method for 301 location header based automatic redirects in curl):

> curl_setopt( , CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
>
> here 3 tells curl module to redirect both 301 as well as 302 requests.
>
> 0,1,2,3 are the valid options for the last argument.
>
> 0 -> do not set any behavior
> 1 -> follow redirect with the same type of request only for 301 redirects.
> 2 -> follow redirect with the same type of request only for 302 redirects.
> 3 -> follow redirect with the same type of request both for 301 and 302 redirects.

See as well: [Request #49571 CURLOPT_POSTREDIR not implemented](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49571) which has some useful comments, like setting a custom request method:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like this might be the one. Will check it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

From [the latest draft of HTTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-17#section-7.3.2):

> Note: For historic reasons, user agents MAY change the request method
> from POST to GET for the subsequent request.  If this behavior is
> undesired, status code 307 (Temporary Redirect) can be used instead.

I think a 303 See Other might be suitable too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, faced with recompiling php because my curl didn't support POSTREDIR i settled for solving this with JQuery.  Hope this helps someone!

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$.post("path/path/callback.php", { "key":"value", "key2":"value2"});

</script>
</head>
hello

</html>
```